# Running Swagger UI with OpenAPI 3.0 YAML file in a Golang Gin API

Tags: go, swagger, openapi

I am relatively new to Golang and have successfully built a RESTful API using the Gin framework. For API documentation, I initially used Swagger 2.0, but I am now migrating to OpenAPI 3.0 for better support and features.

I have written the OpenAPI 3.0 specification in YAML format and I'm looking to integrate Swagger UI to visualize and interact with this documentation. However, I'm unsure about the steps involved in setting up Swagger UI for OpenAPI 3.0 in a Golang Gin project.

Could someone provide a step-by-step guide or point me in the right direction on how to achieve this? Any examples or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out?